# Filter querySet by value of page tag field

Tags: django, django-queryset, wagtail

I'm creating a website using Wagtail. I have a page model called NewsItem. On the page I want to list the most recent news items that have the same tag, alongside the main content of the page itself.

I'm not sure how to get the value of the tag field in order to filter a queryset and return the other news posts.

I've tried various things:

```
def render(self, value): 
    news = NewsItem.objects.live().filter(tags__name=value['tags']).order_by('-date')

    return render_to_string(self.meta.template, { 
        'self': value, 
        'news_items': news, 

    })
```

My tag field looks like this:

```
tags = ClusterTaggableManager(
        through=Tags, blank=True, related_name='news_tag',
        verbose_name="News tags",
        help_text="News, Video..")
```

I don't know if I need the return render_to_string bit, I just found an similar example online.

Any help appreciated.

NewsItem and Tags model looks like:

```
class Tags(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'news.NewsItem', related_name='news_tag')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "News tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "News tags"


class NewsItem(Page):
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(
        through=Tags, blank=True, related_name='news_tag',
        verbose_name="News tags",
        help_text="News, Video..")
```

Comment: add your `models` too

Comment: News and tag models added

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some extra logic. Not sure if this is correct, but if your value['tags'] is a collection (rather than a value), then you need an `IN` statement.

This might work:

`NewsItem.objects.live().filter(tags__name__in=value['tags'])`

If value['tags'] is a list of objects, rather than a list of strings, then you might have to do some formatting on your value['tags']

```
tags = [tag.name for tag in value['tags']
NewsItem.objects.live().filter(tags__name__in=tags)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in